# Logistic Regression giving 99% accuracy. What could be wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

My dataset is of shape `2300 x 35` plus the target variable. 
All my columns are of `object` dtype, it includes numeric and categorical values and so I ran `labelencoding` on the entire dataset. So, I'm not sure if that could be problem here.

I ran `Logistic Regression` and I'm getting 99% accuracy. How is it possible? What could I be doing wrong?
(target column is removed from training and test set)

The accuracy comes down only if I reduce training data to less than 5%, have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Is the dataset inbalanced?

Comment: yes, but I've added `class_weights` attribute

Comment: That makes a difference during training, not testing. Try using f1-score instead

Comment: all my scores are either `1.0` or `0.99`. I even manually randomly selected equal number of samples from the higher class to balance the classes.

Comment: Could it be my label encoding thing? Since it's also giving labels to integers too.

Comment: Hard to say anything without the code, can you post it here as well as some example input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166793/discussion-between-jaskaran-singh-puri-and-shaido).

Comment: You need to post more information.  Dev set results? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

That means one or many independednt variables are higly correlated to target variable. You can Check with below command in Jupyter notebook.

```
import seaborn as sns    
mat.figure(figsize= (20, 10))
sns.heatmap({name_of_dataFrame}.corr(),annot= True)
```

You will get the corr plot with values so remove those columns where value is high.
I hope this will help you.